# TypeScript: how to access a static method of a generic class

Tags: angular, typescript, generics

I have an abstract class:

```
export enum SingularPluralForm {
  SINGULAR,
  PLURAL
};

export abstract class Dog {

  // ...

}
```

And I have a class that extends the abstract class:

```
export class Pug extends Dog {

  // ...

  static readonly kindNames = {
    [SingularPluralForm.SINGULAR]:
      'pug',
    [SingularPluralForm.PLURAL]:
      'pugs'
  };

  // ...

}
```

And also I have a parametrized class that uses a generic and needs access to `kindNames`:

```
export class Playground<T extends Dog> {

  // ...

  getKindName(form: SingularPluralForm) {
    // need to return T.kindNames[form] here...
  }

  // ...

}
```

How to access `T.kindNames[form]` from there?

Please, be so kind as to help. Thank you.

UPD1: I would pass the `Pug` class to the constructor of `Playground`, but the problem is that the `Playground` class is actually an Angular component and it's being initialized by the framework, not manually. :-(

Comment: [this?](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYOwrgtgBAygCgMSgbwFBVgSQHIHECqAMgIIBKANOlHIfqcYagL4DcqAhgEYDOALgE7sAxryhCANu27coAEQD2AcxRQmqCVJlwwy4AA9eoACYyFytBj7teASyFR+wdkfkhxATygBrGyCPZ2CGAZAF4VAG14BAA6GBwCElIAXQAuKAByAAcddPIoSMRomjoGVIzsxW501TY1VF9DfgAzYWA5JQBhXnl+AHUAaV8TFCoQYAB3AAoASjSzNgwfPwCg7jTSYCEeowAeKLy+fl9FAD5a1HVJaWpJd0V+eTA-HYAVKH1DP1NO7r7Br5OIwwWxAhzAIh6k2ynHEdigEHkRmA4i6PTSL2mKjUGEUwF4-38gWAkyaPQgaSimIsGAceLA-BAUF4AAsbNxogikSjftEloTVuFSfwIEkFqpmBcNNcAPLyTIyD7Gb7mGpQAD0aqgIHk3iGICJ3FQY3GN3YdweTyMk20imm0Vx+KGK2JUSKtHohGmLHVmvkXjNRompvNjz8kzMXp9734D34gZNcFu91DVtl8sjGujsaAA)

Comment: There's no `T` at runtime; you need to write ES2015+ classes and give them types.  That means your `Playground` class constructor needs to accept an argument of the other class's constructor if it's going to have a chance to access its properties.  If the code in the previous comment meets your needs I'll write it up as an answer; otherwise please add more detail to the question to distinguish your use case.  Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz, thank you, I considered to do that, but the problem is that `Playground` is actually an Angular component and it's being initialized by the framework.

Comment: Depending on where it is initialized, angular generally provides an additional argument during the registration which specifies the factory to be used. Couldyou please show us where and how you register the object?

Comment: Thank you, @Yennefer! I gave the class as a property (`@Input()`) and it works like a charm!

Comment: You are welcome :)

Comment: @Yennefer, if you post your hint as an answer, I'll mark it as the correct one.

Comment: Will do. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Posted from comments and rephrased to be a little more comprehensive*

Depending on where it is initialized, angular generally provides an additional argument during the registration which specifies the factory to be used.

You can have a look at [factory registration](https://angular.io/api/core/ComponentFactory) for [component loading[2](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader).

Probably, you could be able to solve your issue by binding the property directly with the [@Input](https://angular.io/api/core/Input) decorator on an internal DTO or on the object itself.